# Help to remove handles from leaky bathroom faucet

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

I have a leaky bathroom faucet. There are no screws on the sides of the handle or escutcheon. I cannot figure out how to pry off the top without causing some damage. Maybe someone can look at the picture I've attached and make a suggestion on how best I can fix this thing?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually with that type you pry off the cap on the top and find a screw underneath which holds the handle to the stem of the valve. Probably you pry off the entire cap but it could be only the white center.

Answer (score -1):

yep the screw is under the cap. If you look closely around the edge of the cap, there should be a slot for a small flat head screwdriver to fit into to pry it off.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. The OP already guessed that the screw was under that cap; any suggestions for how to remove it without causing damage? (Please edit your new information into your answer.)